# Prove that $X\triangle\emptyset=X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm working on my proofs involving sets, though this one is not a homework problem, so if you wish to provide your own example, so be it.

I am working on exercise 3.3.14 (1) in Bloch's *Proofs and Fundamentals*. It asks me to prove that $X\triangle \emptyset=X$. The following is what I have so far with comments in brackets "[ ]":

> *Proof:* Let $X$ be some nonempty set. Then $X\triangle \emptyset=\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)\cup\left(\emptyset\setminus
>  X\right)$. Now suppose
>    $x\in\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)\cup\left(\emptyset\setminus
>  X\right)$, then $x\in\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)$ or
>    $x\in\left(\emptyset\setminus X\right)$. [here I decided I would look
>    at either case]
>
> *Case I:* Suppose $x\in\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)$. Then $x\in X$ and $x\not\in\emptyset$, hence
>    $x\in\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)\cup\left(\emptyset\setminus
>  X\right)=x\in X$.
>
> *Case II:* Suppose $x\in\left(\emptyset \setminus X\right)$. Then $x\in\emptyset$ and $x\not\in X$. But $x\not\in\emptyset$ by
>    definition, hence $x\in X$. Thus,
>    $x\in\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)\cup\left(\emptyset\setminus
>  X\right)=x\in X$
>
> Therefore, $X\triangle \emptyset=X$.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: In Case II, $x\notin\varnothing$ does not imply $x\in X$.

Comment: @kennytm How might I make it look something like Case I then? By the way, it is "\emptyset" I think (:

Comment: You've made a mistake in your *case II*, and even if this was fixed, you've only shown that $X \triangle \emptyset \subseteq X$.

Comment: @kennytm But $p$ and $\neg p$ imply everything. I think this is the idea behind the OP's argument.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see, I will go back and fix this.

Comment: You're probably better off proving that $\emptyset \setminus X = \emptyset$ and $X \setminus \emptyset = X$, then concluding the desired statement as a consequence.

Comment: Something which is unquestionably wrong is writing $\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)\cup\left(\emptyset\setminus
 X\right)=x$ and $\left(X\setminus\emptyset\right)\cup\left(\emptyset\setminus
 X\right)=x$.

Comment: You do need to prove the other direction. Also, I'd let your case 2 be case 1 and say it isn't possible so it must be in...then continue on. Or you can just do what Travis just answered with.

Comment: @GitGud That makes sense, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can dispense with showing that an arbitrary element of each set is contained in the other by showing a few basic facts which are already essentially contained in your proof, namely that for any set $X$ we have
\begin{align}
X - \varnothing &= X \\
\varnothing - X &= \varnothing
\end{align}
Once we have these (trivial) facts handy, we can simply expand
$$X \triangle \varnothing = (X - \varnothing) \cup (\varnothing - X) = X \cup \varnothing = X.$$ The last equality again requires proof, and again this is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

By other definition of $\Delta$:
$$X\Delta\emptyset=(X\cup\emptyset)\setminus (X\cap\emptyset)=X\setminus \emptyset=X$$

Comment: you are welcome.